# How to destructure object assignments in JS objects after the object is initialized?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a shorter way to assign an "undestructured" property to an object *after* the object is initialized.

```js
const a = 'foo';
const out = { a }; // this is during object initialization
// is there any similar shortcut to the above after out is initialized?
const b = 'bar';
// i'm looking for a streamlined alternative to the following line
out.b = b; // this works, but is there a shorter way to assign property b to object out?
// out { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', }
```

Comment: I guess you could do `Object.assign(out, {b: 'bar'})` (which is one line as opposed to 2), or, if you're happy creating a new object you could do `const c = {...out, b}`

Comment: Just drop the `const` and use `out.b = 'bar';`? Or `Object.assign(out, {b})`, but that's not really shorter

Comment: It seems you are not looking for a destructuring pattern, but rather a property definition shorthand.